# Power BI: From Folder 5 Million + Data taking too long to refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

What I am trying to do (obviously not efficient), is to refresh data from the folder using given parameters that I have chosen (like Start/EndData, System). I have a code down so you can easily follow my steps, and I would be very keen if I can have any suggest/tip how to make my query more efficient, to lower refresh time and so on.

My idea was to have parameter within PBI where I can easily adjust what I need and with refresh to manage it, like standard. But I have huge amount of data, that are saved somewhere on the Companies Drive (not online or in Database), and I am pulling them, convert them (binary to csv for instance), transform and then load into PBI. But it is taking up to 15 minutes to refresh.

```
let
Source =Folder.Files("Q:\Objekt\ABC\DEF\XYZ\1. Source Data"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".dif")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Content", "Folder Path"}),
#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Text Between 
Delimiters", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([Folder Path], "\", "\", 6, 0), type text),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters",{{"Text Between 
Delimiters", "System"}}),
BinaryToCSV = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each 
Csv.Document(Binary.Buffer([Content]),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=23, Encoding=1200, 
QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(BinaryToCSV,{"Content"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"System"}, {{"Count", each _, type table 
[Folder Path=text, System=text, Custom=table]}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Custom"}, {"Custom"}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Count", each [System] = SystemToChoose),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Custom", {"Column1", 
"Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", 
"Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", 
"Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23"}, 
{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", 
"Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", 
"Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23"}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Column1", "Date&Time"}, 
{"Column2", "P0 [mbar]"}, {"Column3", "P1 [mbar]"}, {"Column4", "P3 [mbar]"}, {"Column5", "P7 
[mbar]"}, {"Column6", "PS160 [mbar]"}, {"Column7", "P190 [mbar]"}, {"Column8", "P220 [mbar]"}, 
{"Column9", "Q1 [ppb]"}, {"Column10", "Q2 [ppb]"}, {"Column11", "Q3 [ppb]"}, {"Column12", "Q4 
[ppb]"}, {"Column13", "T11 [°C]"}, {"Column14", "T21 [°C]"}, {"Column15", "T31 [°C]"}, 
{"Column16", "T12 [°C]"}, {"Column17", "T22 [°C]"}, {"Column18", "T32 [°C]"}, {"Column19", 
"T01 [°C]"}, {"Column20", "T02 [°C]"}, {"Column21", "FM1 [slm]"}, {"Column22", "FM2 [slm]"}, 
{"Column23", "FM3 [slm]"}}),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns1", each [#"P0 [mbar]"] <> "" and [#"P0 
[mbar]"] <> "mbar" and [#"P0 [mbar]"] <> "P_0"),
#"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows2",{{"System", Text.Clean, type text}, 
{"Date&Time", Text.Clean, type text}, {"P0 [mbar]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"P1 [mbar]", 
Text.Clean, type text}, {"P3 [mbar]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"P7 [mbar]", Text.Clean, type 
text}, {"PS160 [mbar]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"P190 [mbar]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"P220 
[mbar]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"Q1 [ppb]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"Q2 [ppb]", Text.Clean, 
type text}, {"Q3 [ppb]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"Q4 [ppb]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T11 
[°C]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T21 [°C]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T31 [°C]", Text.Clean, 
type text}, {"T12 [°C]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T22 [°C]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T32 
[°C]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T01 [°C]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"T02 [°C]", Text.Clean, 
type text}, {"FM1 [slm]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"FM2 [slm]", Text.Clean, type text}, {"FM3 
[slm]", Text.Clean, type text}}),
#"Removed Alternate Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(#"Cleaned Text",0,5,1),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Alternate Rows",{{"System", type text}, 
{"Date&Time", type datetime}, {"P0 [mbar]", Int64.Type}, {"P1 [mbar]", Int64.Type}, {"P3 
[mbar]", Int64.Type}, {"P7 [mbar]", Int64.Type}, {"PS160 [mbar]", Int64.Type}, {"P190 [mbar]", 
Int64.Type}, {"P220 [mbar]", Int64.Type}, {"Q1 [ppb]", Int64.Type}, {"Q2 [ppb]", Int64.Type}, 
{"Q3 [ppb]", Int64.Type}, {"Q4 [ppb]", Int64.Type}, {"T11 [°C]", type number}, {"T21 [°C]", 
type number}, {"T31 [°C]", type number}, {"T12 [°C]", type number}, {"T22 [°C]", type number}, 
{"T32 [°C]", type number}, {"T01 [°C]", type number}, {"T02 [°C]", type number}, {"FM1 [slm]", 
Int64.Type}, {"FM2 [slm]", Int64.Type}, {"FM3 [slm]", Int64.Type}}),
DateFilter = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [#"Date&Time"] >= StartDate and 
[#"Date&Time"] <= EndDate),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(DateFilter,{"System"})
in
#"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: If you have a a lot of data, you probably need to integrate your data. You can collect your data in a single database or an instance of analysis service to get better performance.

Comment: @Carbon4horse Do you think if I convert those original files to .txt or .csv and import them so, that will add up to my efficiency? My original data is stored as .dif where I need to transform them all to .csv within PQ.

Comment: You can maybe try with csv File directly imported in Power BI but I think that if you have too much data you need to use a database (realtionnal)  or an Olap solution ( like analysis service)